# C++ read internal file Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

There is a file located in `/data/user/0/com.uniquestudio.android.iemoji/files/yibaiwan.txt`.

I want to read the file in JNI.

```
ifstream in.open(in_file_name, ios::binary);
LOGD("%d", in.good() ? 1 : 0);
```

However `in.good()` is always `false`. What's wrong?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

## EDIT for permission

As you know, INTERNAL_STORAGE does not require permission.

## EDIT for file info

The file is `encrypted` file. When I use above code to read normal file, everything works well. Now I want to read the `encrypted` file then `decrypt` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone meets same issue, you maybe create file as `root` role. If you edit file or create file under `root`, you can not visit it anymore with normal user role.

Comment: good point. If a file is located in internal app storage but not created by the app, it is likely to be with wrong access permissions.